# How to modify code so it writes the values in two columns?

Tags: java

```
double total = 0;
    while(in.hasNextDouble()){
        double value = in.nextDouble();
        out.printf("%15.2f\n", value);
        total = total + value;
    }
out.printf("Total: %8.2f\n", total);
```

A short snippet of the code I'm trying to modify. It currently outputs whatever I had in an input file row by row.

```
    double total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while(in.hasNextDouble()){

        if(count == 0){
            double value = in.nextDouble();
            out.printf("%4.2f", value);
            count = 1;
            total = total + value;
        }
        else if(count == 1){
            double value = in.nextDouble();
            out.printf("%15.2f\n", value);
            count = 0;
            total = total + value;
        }
    }

    if(count == 1){ 
        out.print("\n");
    }
    out.printf("Total: %8.2f\n", total);
```

I modified it that way and it works, but I feel like it's really long. Is there is a shorter method I'm missing?

Comment: Read two values and output them in a `String.format`?

Comment: Depending on the complexity, printing with `\t` (tabulator) may also yield the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this. One way:

```
double total = 0;
while(in.hasNextDouble()){
    double value = in.nextDouble();
     out.printf("%4.2f", value);
     total += value;

     if ( in.hasNextDouble() {
         double value = in.nextDouble();
         out.printf("%15.2f", value);
         total += value;
    } else {
        out.print("\n");
        break;
    }
    out.print("\n");
}
out.printf("\nTotal: %8.2f\n", total);
```